# Desktop App Workflow Error When Logging In

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-oauth

Our desktop application integrates with Facebook using the desktop app workflow and for approx. 18 months has been working without any problems. However, we are starting to get reports from some users that they cannot get past the login process.

When the login is successful Facebook should be attaching the access_token to the redirect_uri. Our application detects this and moves the user to the main part of our Facebook integration. What appears to be happening in some situations is that the access_token parameter is missing which causes our application to leave our embedded browser window open with the following message from Facebook:
*"Success

SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone."*

What is strange is that this does not occur with all Facebook accounts and which Facebook accounts it occurs with seems to be changing. For example, we had a report of this approx. 1 week ago but could not duplicate it with my own Facebook account or with a colleague's Facebook account. Today, I still cannot duplicate it with my own Facebook account but my colleague now gets the problem.

The URL our code sends to Facebook is:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup&scope=read_friendlists,user_photos,friends_photos,user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags,user_events,friends_events,user_groups,friends_groups

Reading the latest API documentation it looks like they recommend a different way to connect which we have also tried:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=read_friendlists,user_photos,friends_photos,user_photo_video_tags,friends_photo_video_tags,user_events,friends_events,user_groups,friends_groups&response_type=token

To rule out our application as the cause we have tried these URLs directly within a web browser. What we find is that when using my Facebook account the browser re-directs to the success URL that includes the access_token parameter but when using my colleague's account the browser re-directs to the success URL that includes the access_token and then immediately re-directs again to the success URL without the access_token.

so... As far as we can tell this is either:
a) A change to the API which we cannot find documented anywhere
b) A bug in Facebook
c) Something that is now controlled by the user's Facebook security settings

Is there anybody who could explain why Facebook is acting differently with different accounts and how we can go about fixing this?

Thanks.
Kevin.

Comment: It would probably be helpful for a view of the whole scenario to post the code that makes the web request too. Just for completeness.

Comment: The two URLs above are enough to duplicate the problem. Simply replace client_id=xxxx with an application ID and put it into a browser. I can add our test application ID but not sure if that is wise.

Comment: As a first poster, I was reviewing your question and trying to help you glean more answers from the community. Perhaps fiddler results or similar to include here might be useful. Just trying to help you out in a field of expertise that is not within my personal sphere.

Comment: My api code has been working for months, but suddenly the /me/posts bit stopped working. Even the graph API test page does not work! https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my desktop applications.
And I just solve it with careful reading in ht*ps://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-for-desktop/. The solution is to change redirect_uri from ht*p://www.facebook.com/... into ht*ps://www.facebook.com/...

Hope this will help you just like it help me

NB:

> > change ht*p into http
> >     sorry i have to change the http into ht*p so that i can post the answer.